# Is @XmlElement necessary for Jaxb

Tags: json, xml, jaxb, jersey

My question is, whether it is necessary to add @XmlElement before each element in your pojo to be picked up by jaxb, when making a JSON response. I am using jersey-json 1.17 . The reason I ask this is because, [the example given on Jersey site](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/examples/jaxb/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/jaxb/JaxbXmlRootElement.java) does not use the annotation.

I get an out put as `{}`, but when I add @XmlElement before the attributes, I get the expected JSON output. Am I doing something wrong, because of which my JSON string is empty ?

My code :

The vertices list is populated in the constructor.

**This produces the wrong output of `{}`**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class SquareModel {
    List<Float> vertices = new ArrayList<Float>();
    ....
}
```

**Whereas this produces the a correct JSON string :**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class SquareModel {
    @XmlElement(name="vertices")
    List<Float> vertices = new ArrayList<Float>();
    ....
}
```

**My resource class which returns the JSON**

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public SquareModel getJsonString() {
    return new SquareModel();
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: although it is not required to put `@XmlElement`, for some reason i am still not getting the fields in the output Json without it.  Although when `@XmlAcessorType` was added, i started getting all the fields even without the `@XmlElement` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, by default a JAXB (JSR-22@) implementation will treat all public fields and properties (get/set combinations) as mapped (not requiring the `@XmlElement` annotation).

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

If you wish to annotate a field I would recommend annotating your class with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Answer (score 0):

According to this http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#json.jaxb.approach.section
You should have this annotation (I'm also using it in my code, even though it XML oriented, but it gives me cool JSON also)

> Taking this approach will save you a lot of time, if you want to
>   easily produce/consume both JSON and XML data format. Because even
>   then you will still be able to use a unified Java model. Another
>   advantage is simplicity of working with such a model, as JAXB
>   leverages annotated POJOs and these could be handled as simple Java
>   beans.
>
> A disadvantage of JAXB based approach could be if you need to work
>   with a very specific JSON format. Then it could be difficult to find a
>   proper way to get such a format produced and consumed. This is a
>   reason why a lot of configuration options are provided, so that you
>   can control how things get serialized out and deserialized back.
>
> Following is a very simple example of how a JAXB bean could look like.
>
> Example 5.3. Simple JAXB bean implementation

```
@XmlRootElement
   public class MyJaxbBean {
     public String name;
     public int age;

     public MyJaxbBean() {} // JAXB needs this

     public MyJaxbBean(String name, int age) {
       this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
    }
  }
```